# Why did my preg_match() suddenly stop working? php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

Hi I have had problems with these preg_match before. I know it has something to do with the "delimeter" but I don't know why and how to fix...

This function was perfectly working for a week. But suddenly today it stopped matching. I thought that it had something to do with some other code that I had added during the day. So to localise the problem I rolled back my files to a previous version where it was working. Only to realise that it is no longer working..............

Is it something with the memory in my server that caches some of the pattern? Or how can it be that something that have been working isn't working anymore?

This is my function, it was beautifully returning color code in all allowed formats, but now it is ONLY returning #000000 no matter what I feed it.

```
function validateColor($input){
    $match = preg_match("/^(\#[\da-f]{3}|\#[\da-f]{6}|rgba\(((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\s*,\s*){2}((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\s*)(,\s*(0\.\d+|1))\)|hsla\(\s*((\d{1,2}|[1-2]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|60)))\s*,\s*((\d{1,2}|100)\s*%)\s*,\s*((\d{1,2}|100)\s*%)(,\s*(0\.\d+|1))\)|rgb\(((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\s*,\s*){2}((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\s*)|hsl\(\s*((\d{1,2}|[1-2]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|60)))\s*,\s*((\d{1,2}|100)\s*%)\s*,\s*((\d{1,2}|100)\s*%)\))$/",$input);
    if(!$match){
        return '#000000';
    }
    return $input;
}
```

Comment: You could simplify it to `if (preg_match(...)) { ... }`. The pattern [is valid](https://regex101.com/r/ezSAEO/1).

Comment: Is `$input` what you think it is?

Comment: Please detail what you are trying to do.  Ex. what should match, what should not.  Then we can look if your regex is good or not.  Give examples of $input, that are good, and that are not good.

Comment: what is your input value?

Comment: protip 1: with lengthy complicated regex like that, it pays to use `PCRE_EXTENDED` and split and document it over several lines. That way, you don't need to figure out what it does exactly every time you need to read it.

Comment: thanks, look here https://regex101.com/r/A2IjNO/4 this i what i copied, and it worked. for a week or two. now it doesnt work anymore. I rolled back my code to previous commits, still not working. Is something stuck in the memory on my server where the code is running and breaking the regex?

Comment: No, forget that memory thing.  What is $input (valid and invalid)?

Comment: protip 2: write a unit test for it exercising all kinds of inputs.

Comment: just tried to feed it : rgb(234, 160, 160) - didn't work

Comment: You are missing a `\)`, see https://regex101.com/r/A2IjNO/13. So, the regex did not work with `rgb(...)` from the very beginning.

Comment: just a side note. you should consider using a js color picker library. with that you won't have to worry about this.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure you match a `)` in `rgb` alternative, add `\)` there:

```
/^(\#[\da-f]{3}|\#[\da-f]{6}|rgba\(((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\s*,\s*){2}((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\s*)(,\s*(0\.\d+|1))\)|hsla\(\s*((\d{1,2}|[1-2]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|60)))\s*,\s*((\d{1,2}|100)\s*%)\s*,\s*((\d{1,2}|100)\s*%)(,\s*(0\.\d+|1))\)|rgb\(((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\s*,\s*){2}((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\s*)\)|hsl\(\s*((\d{1,2}|[1-2]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|60)))\s*,\s*((\d{1,2}|100)\s*%)\s*,\s*((\d{1,2}|100)\s*%)\))$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ezSAEO/2)

[Expanded version](https://regex101.com/r/A2IjNO/14):

```
^(
  \#[\da-f]{3}
 |\#[\da-f]{6}
 |rgba\(
         ((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\s*,\s*){2}
         ((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\s*)
         (,\s*(0\.\d+|1))
      \)
 |hsla\(
       \s*((\d{1,2}|[1-2]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|60)))\s*,
       \s*((\d{1,2}|100)\s*%)\s*,
       \s*((\d{1,2}|100)\s*%)
       (,\s*(0\.\d+|1))
     \)
 |rgb\(
         ((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\s*,\s*){2}
         ((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2([0-4]\d|5[0-5]))\s*)
       \) # HERE
 |hsl\(
       \s*((\d{1,2}|[1-2]\d{2}|3([0-5]\d|60)))\s*,
       \s*((\d{1,2}|100)\s*%)\s*,
       \s*((\d{1,2}|100)\s*%)
     \)
)$
```

Comment: Thanks! that worked. Still a mystery to me why it worked a week ago, will review all my commits and see if i at some point broke the string.